# Mysql trigger or coding in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, triggers

I have a table `hardware_description`:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Computer_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Emp_id           | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| PC_type          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Operating_system | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Product_key      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Assign_date      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DVD_ROM          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CPU              | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| IP_address       | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| MAC_address      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Model_name       | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Model_number     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Monitor          | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Processor        | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Product_name     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RAM              | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Serial_number    | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Vendor_id        | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

`Emp_id` is `foreign key` from `employees` table.

When I update a particular row, I want the existing data for that row to be saved in another table along with the **timestamp** of that `update` action. Now,

a) Shall I use `PHP` code (`PDO` `transaction`) to first grab that row & insert in another table then perform the `UPDATE` query on that particular row?

b) Use `trigger` on this table.

Which process is better practice & more efficient? Is there another way of achieving this?

I have not used `trigger` in my short career so far but I can do it if it is better practice.

Comment: It depends on your situation and resources. Triggers are a good way of doing stuff like this, but it does mean, as your program evolves, that you will have to maintain two systems in parallel. It  may or may not be something you want to do; only you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do a trigger, it would be a lot better to use that.

The reason for this is that if for some reason you forget to write the PHP code to do this (in some weird situation) - you would have missing, unrelated data - otherwise known as orphaned data, which does not have a corresponding row or set of rows.

Here's the link to the MySQL documentation page for triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html